# FlatList onPress function rerender causes lag after usestate update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

So we have a flat list with roughly 200/300 buttons
These buttons get passed a function that shows a ad after 5 clicks.
So we used useState to count the click.

But.. because we update the count inside the function, it calls it selfs again and it rerenders all flatlist items/buttons and causes lag/delay.

***"What do you mean with lag?"***
For example normally you can spam click the button and its all fine, but when the  `setCount(prev => prev +1)` is uncommented it just slowly freeze and falls behind

**Code**:

```js
import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity,FlatList, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const data = ['IMAGINE 200 items here.']

const test = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const TestFunction = useCallback(async () => {
        setCount(prev => prev + 1);

        if (count === 5) {
            /*for example show a add*/
            showAd();
        }
    }, [count]);


    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList data={data} renderItem={() => React.useMemo(<TouchableOpacity onPress={TestFunction}>
                <Text>Test</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>)}>

            </FlatList>
        </View>
    );
};


const showAd = () => {
    /*for example show a add*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should split the TestFunction in two

```
const addClick = useCallback(() => { setCount(prev => prev + 1) }, []) 
// this doesn't need count dependency
```

and

```
const showAdOnCountThreshold = useEffect(() => { if (count === 5) showAd() }, [count] 
// this gets called after updating the count
```

Also, your `React.memo` doesn't do anything because it doesn't have the dependency set. But now that you have `addClick` which never changes, then the Touchables have no reason to change (as far as prop changes are concerned).

So you can do:

```
const renderClickCountButton = React.useCallback(() => (
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={addClick}>...</TouchableOpacity>
), [addClick])
```

and then

```
<FlatList renderItem={renderClickCountButton}
```